# How do I boot up in windows after using the wubi installer

Tags: installation, windows-7, wubi

I used the wubi installer (using a 15 Gb install size, presuming this was the amount it would use as its partition of the hard drive, but apparently it doesn't use a partition) on Windows 7. On reboot Ubuntu booted up without a dual boot menu. What can I do to get back into my Windows environment?

I do use 2 hard drives with Windows files on the `C:` drive (along with music and photos) and the wubi installed on the `D:` drive (along with games and a back up of the Windows on the `C:` drive). Even when booting from `C:` drive it still boots up Ubuntu.

I need a fix that does not involve reformatting either hard drive preferably, or perhaps I am just missing an obvious option in the Ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a Compaq computer, when you turn it on, change the boot-order and put the C:\ Drive first
You can access this by pressing ESC when you turn on your computer, although im not sure if its equal for ALL computers, hope it helped! And best of luck :)